# How to bring a (non-Git) copy of a repo into the Git fold as a branch

Tags: git, branch

I have essentially a feature "psuedo-branch" that was created outside of Git starting at point "x". Meanwhile, inside Git "master" I've made significant changes from point "x".

Now, if I create a branch, and copy-paste all my feature changes, it, of course, overrides all the changes in "master" when I try to merge.

How do I tell Git that this feature branch should actually start at point "x" and I want to fold all the master changes into it, not override them?

Answer (score 0):

Aha!

By creating a branch from point "x" using "Create Branch From" in VSCode which I assume is the same as `git branch -f <branchname> <commit>` I can then copy-paste in my changes, then merge in the "master" branch and resolve any conflicts.

Man I love Git.